# slideshow module for drupal

Tags: drupal, module

i'm in need of a drupal module which gives a slideshow from the images uploaded by the user..i saw the slideshow module but can't understand where to apply the settings..
thanks for ur help..
slideshow format:

```
                     current image displayed here



 previous_button   image image image image image image image image   next_button
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use CCK + Views + the jQuery Cycle plugin. No custom "slideshow" module needed.

Answer (score 0):

The settings can be found at `www.example.com/admin/settings/slideshow`.

If you want custom slideshows, easiets is probably

1. CCK + filefield + imagefield to be able to  upload images
2. Imagecache to cache and style the images (max width and height)
3. Taxonomy to be able to indicate which gallery the image belongs to
4. Views to create the gallery.
5. [Insert random jQuery pludin here] for the slideshow effect. You could use something like thickbox, but there are so many, that you can just take your pick.

Comment: i found that out..but donno how to create slideshow from a content type..by default, a node only allows one image to be uploaded rite?
i use gallery module, but can't figure out how to make it work with slideshow module. should i use any other module with it to work? or simply, is there a better module to produce slideshows?

Comment: By default, no image can be uploaded to your node. You might want to alter you question to reflect what your actual question is.

Comment: i'll put it simple: i need a gallery with slideshows..the user should be able to upload the images that he wants for slideshow..